# VB 2008 Periodic Tasks

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, scheduled-tasks

What's the easiest way to run a periodic task in the background in VB?

For example: Update a label every second with the current time, while still allowing the form to be available.

Comment: Web Form or Windows Form or WPF or SilverLight?

Answer (score 6):

1. Add a `Timer` component to your form
2. Set its `Interval` to the time between updates
3. Enable the timer (by setting its `Enabled` property or calling its `Start` method)
4. Handle its `Tick` event by doing whatever updates are necessary.

Your handler would look something like this:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
                        ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

   label1.Text = GetCurrentStatus()

End Sub
```